# Can I repair this dent on a finished surface?

Tags: repair, wood, doors, closet

I have a closet door that has a finished surface (melamine panel?). Unfortunately, I dented it with the bed and now there's a giant dent and some break in the wood.

Is there a way to fix this or is it to the point of unrepairable? If it is repairable, any suggestions or recommendations as to the best way to fix it?

[image: dent]

[image: dent]

Comment: pry it back out gently and glue it in place. it won't be prefect, but it won't cast an eye-catching  shadow

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a way to repair the door but I don't see it being easy or very cost efficient.  I have a suggestion that might help you, have you considered flipping the door around so that the damage is on the inside. You will most probably have to reverse the hinges.  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I do this with couch cushions and it works well...

Comment: This may be out of my expertise to tackle something like this... but good suggestion! Thank you.